# Emoji hex showing as &amp;#x1f37a; instead of &#x1f37a in source code hence not being processed and displayed

Tags: html

In my email template I passing the emoji html hex values as `&#x1f37a`. When I view the email it shows the value as `&#x1f37a` instead of the equivalent emoji. When I view source it shows `&amp;#x1f37a`. When I do edit as html in firebug and then remove the `amp;` then it shows the correct emoji. Can you please advise how to fix this issue

Comment: Maybe you are missing the ";" at the end, like this "&#x1f37a;"?

Comment: Thanks Matic. I've added the ";" still doesn't show .. When I view the mail source in firebug it shows &amp;#x1f37a;  when I do edit as html and then remove the amp; then it show the emoji

Comment: Are you HTML Encoding your email before sending it? That could change the "&" to "&amp;" and mess things up.

Comment: I'm using mandrill to send email. I'm setting the message value in GlobalMergeVar("message" "&#127866;"). Don't really know if mandrill is encoding on his side.

Comment: Is there a way a can pass the emoji hex value so that even if encoded by mandrill it will show as & instead of &amp;  I've tried passing as %26, but this doesn't work . Or is there a way to specify the value should not be encoded.

Comment: This is a Mandrill specific question. Have you tried contacting their support?